# the most important books for project manager

Tags: project-management

I'm trying to learn about critical skills for a PM and how to develop them, so I am looking for books that can assist me in this.

"Peopleware" and "Code Complete" I think are a "must", but are there other more important books or other must-haves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clean Coder by Robert Martin is a must have. Describes the relationship between PM and a development team very well.

Comment: do you mean this? http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: Also a very good book, but I meant http://www.amazon.de/gp/aw/d/0137081073